# Telegram Bot API C# How to get All Pinned Messages?

Tags: c#, telegram, telegram-bot

Telegram added the feature to pin more than one message. I'm doing it like this:

```
            var chat = botClient.GetChatAsync(chatid).Result;

            pinnedmsgtxt = chat.PinnedMessage.Text;

            pinnedmsg= chat.PinnedMessage;
```

but I can only get the last message that was pinned. Any way to get all of them? Am I missing something? I'm using https://github.com/TelegramBots/telegram.bot

Answer (score 0):

Use `messages.search` method with `inputMessagesFilterPinned` filter.

Please read more here:

[Pin API](https://core.telegram.org/api/pin)

[Message Search API](https://core.telegram.org/method/messages.search)

[Pinned messages filter](https://core.telegram.org/constructor/inputMessagesFilterPinned)